# Clickonce installation/upgrade shows no icon in the taskbar

Tags: .net, clickonce

When upgrading/installing a Clickonce application (Winforms, .NET SP1) the window in the taskbar looks like this:

[image: Windows Taskbar screenshot]

The actual dialog of the download/install shows the app icon. How do I get it to show something other than this silly icon in the taskbar ?

Comment: I experienced the same. The application icon is displayed on the download window itself but not in the task bar.
Since there is no other way of providing an application icon I think it's a bug / impossible.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't edit comments; but on a Windows 2003 machine it's the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but you can't modify that icon. Yep, it's a bummer.